# SVG SMIL animation breaks on repeat in Safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari, smil

I'm using SMIL for the animation, and javascript to add/remove a class and trigger the toggle.

Everything works fine in Chrome, but it falls apart in Safari. The animation works in Safari on the first toggle, but then breaks, only firing off some parts of the animation.

Link to the Codepen here: http://codepen.io/matthewcpaul/pen/EaqmpE

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var burgerMenu = document.querySelector(".ibmburger");
burgerMenu.onclick = function() {
  if (burgerMenu.classList.contains("close")) {
   document.getElementById("close-menu").beginElement();
    burgerMenu.classList.remove("close");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("open-menu").beginElement();
    burgerMenu.classList.add("close");   
  }
}
```

```css
.ibmburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -32px 0 0 -32px;
  background: #734098;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg class="ibmburger" id="svg-all" width="64" height="64" viewbox="-50 0 200 200">
  <path id="top-line" fill="transparent" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="100" d="M 0,70 C 50,70 50,70 100,70">
    <animate
      xlink:href="#top-line"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 0,70 C 50,70 50,70 100,70"
      to="M 0,100 C 0,34.3 100,34.3 100,100"
      dur="250ms"
      begin="indefinite"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 .1 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"
      id="open-menu"></animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#top-line"
      attributeName="stroke-width"
      from="8"
      to="4"
      dur="200ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 50ms"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#top-line"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 0,100 C 0,34.3 100,34.3 100,100"
      to="M 0,70 C 50,70 50,70 100,70"
      dur="250ms"
      begin="indefinite"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 .1 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"
      id="close-menu"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#top-line"
      attributeName="stroke-width"
      from="4"
      to="8"
      dur="200ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 50ms"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
  </path>
  <path id="bot-line" fill="transparent" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="100" d="M 0,130 C 50,130 50,130 100,130">
    <animate
      xlink:href="#bot-line"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 0,130 C 50,130 50,130 100,130"
      to="M 0,100 C 0,165.7 100,165.7 100,100"
      dur="250ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 0ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 .1 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#bot-line"
      attributeName="stroke-width"
      from="8"
      to="4"
      dur="200ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 50ms"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#bot-line"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 0,100 C 0,165.7 100,165.7 100,100"
      to="M 0,130 C 50,130 50,130 100,130"
      dur="250ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 0ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 .1 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#bot-line"
      attributeName="stroke-width"
      from="4"
      to="8"
      dur="200ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 50ms"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
  </path>

  <path id="middle-1" fill="transparent" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="100" d="M 0,100 C 50,100 50,100 100,100" transform="rotate(0 0 0)">
      <animate
      xlink:href="#middle-1"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 0,100 C 50,100 50,100 100,100"
      to="M 25,100 C 50,100 50,100 75,100"
      dur="100ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 0ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 0 1 1"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
      <animateTransform
      xlink:href="#middle-1"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 50 100"
      to="45 50 100"
      dur="250ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 100ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines="0 .6 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"</animateTransform>
    <animateTransform
      xlink:href="#middle-1"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="rotate"
      from="45 50 100"
      to="0 50 100"
      dur="150ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 0ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 0 1 1"
      fill="freeze"</animateTransform>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#middle-1"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 25,100 C 50,100 50,100 75,100"
      to="M 0,100 C 50,100 50,100 100,100"
      dur="100ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 150ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines="0 .6 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
  </path>
  <path id="middle-2" fill="transparent" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0" stroke-miterlimit="100" d="M 0,100 C 50,100 50,100 100,100" transform="rotate(0 0 0)">
      <animate
      xlink:href="#middle-2"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 0,100 C 50,100 50,100 100,100"
      to="M 25,100 C 50,100 50,100 75,100"
      dur="100ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 0ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 0 1 1"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#middle-2"
      attributeName="stroke-width"
      from="0"
      to="8"
      dur="1ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 99ms"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animateTransform
      xlink:href="#middle-2"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 50 100"
      to="-45 50 100"
      dur="250ms"
      begin="open-menu.begin + 100ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines="0 .6 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"</animateTransform>
    <animateTransform
      xlink:href="#middle-2"
      attributeName="transform" 
      attributeType="XML"
      type="rotate"
      from="-45 50 100"
      to="0 50 100"
      dur="150ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 0ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines=".5 0 1 1"
      fill="freeze"</animateTransform>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#middle-2"
      attributeName="stroke-width"
      from="8"
      to="0"
      dur="1ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 150ms"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
    <animate
      xlink:href="#middle-2"
      attributeName="d"
      from="M 25,100 C 50,100 50,100 75,100"
      to="M 0,100 C 50,100 50,100 100,100"
      dur="100ms"
      begin="close-menu.begin + 150ms"
      calcMode="spline"
      keyTimes="0;1"
      keySplines="0 .6 .3 1"
      fill="freeze"</animate>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Sadly, no. I have moved on from my SMIL experiments.